# Fuzzy Find C++ function definition

Tags: tags, filetype-c++, navigation

I am looking for a way to fuzzy find C++ function/method definition in NeoVim.   A function definition can look like this:

```
bool Cls::func() {
bool func() {
bool Cls::func(unsigned some, bool argument) {
```

Would there be a solution where I can start typing something like `fnc` and it would list all the lines that look like that pattern so I can choose which line to go to?  It would work similar to the CtrlP plugin but would only list the function definitions for the currently open buffer.

Comment: Have you looked into [`vimgrep`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/quickfix.txt.html#%3Avimgrep)?

Comment: No, but https://github.com/haya14busa/incsearch.vim looks promising, using converter, just have not figured out how to do it.

Comment: I think `[I` might help a little